# Xcode export Step failed: IDEDistributionThinningStep

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm using Xcode version 8.2.1 and Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2

Having issues exporting archive using Xcode build command:

```
 xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath {archivePath} -exportPath {exportPath} -exportOptionsPlist {exportOptionsPlistPath}
```

While running this command i'm getting this issue:

```
[MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7fa4d888ee20>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.
```

Also when trying to export manually, and choosing export for specific device i'm getting this error :
 [image: No applicable device found]

The exportOptionsPlist file looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried to play with the thinning param but nothing helped.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this problem?

I recently run into this issue ... and I am still working on it. So far, I see a problem in your exportOptionsPlist file, it should also include a teamID, I mean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>XX..XX</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also, the error `No applicable devices found` might appear if one of the framework/library you app depends on, does not support bitcode but your app requires it.

I recommend you to follow this issue in fastline where it is described how to fully debug this error: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8737.

Regards.